# Does "with io.open" close the file automatically?

Tags: python, io

For example:

```
with io.open('Example.txt','r',encoding='utf-8') as temp:
    ExampleText=temp.readlines()[1]
```

Do I need to close it manually, like:

```
with io.open('Example.txt','r',encoding='utf-8') as temp:
    ExampleText=temp.readlines()[1]
temp.close()
```

Comment: According to docs at https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#high-level-module-interface it's alias of built-in `open()` so no, you don't need to close after `with` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: No, you don't need to close the stream when used with the `with` statement.

The reason for this is that the `TextIOWrapper` object returned by `io.open` is a context manager which will call `close` on the underlying file when a context is exited.

To verify this behavior we can simply call `__exit__` explicitly and then try to read the file:

```
>>> import io
>>> foo = io.open("foo.txt", "w+")
>>> foo.__exit__()
>>> foo.read()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Which demonstrates that the file is in fact closed when `__exit__` is called, which happens automatically when the `with` block is exited.

Note that there is one case where the file descriptor will not be closed on `__exit__` and that is the case where a file-descriptor is passed to `io.open` rather than a file name or object along with a value of `False` for the `closefd` argument:

```
>>> import os
>>> file_ = open("foo.txt", "w+")
>>> foo = io.open(file_.fileno(), closefd=False)
>>> foo.__exit__()
>>> # the IOTextWrapper is closed
>>> foo.read()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
>>> # but the underlying file descriptor is not closed.
>>> os.read(file_.fileno(), 512)
b''
```

If you pass a value of `True` for the `closefd` argument than the passed file descriptor is closed on context exit:

```
>>> with io.open(file_.fileno(), closefd=True):
...     pass
>>> os.read(file_.fileno(), 512)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Docs describing this behavior in detail can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/io.html#raw-file-i-o).

Answer (score 1):

No, You don't need to close it manually.

Answer (score 0):

From the [reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html),

> If a file descriptor is given, it is closed when the returned I/O object is closed, unless closefd is set to False.

So if you provide a file descriptor and want to manually close it (because you might use descriptor later) you call it as

```
import os
import io
fd = os.open("foo.txt", os.O_RDONLY)
io.open(fd, 'r', encoding='utf-8', closefd=False)
```

Comment: From the same reference: `file is either a string giving the pathname (absolute or relative to the current working directory) of the file to be opened or an integer file descriptor of the file to be wrapped`. `'Example.txt'` is not a file descriptor and I am not sure if this is the answer to the question

Comment: closefd doesn't work this way. per the docs, closefd prevents the file descriptor from being closed when the `close` method of the IOWrapper object is called if the initial passed value is a file descriptor. in fact using closefd this way throws an error: >>> foo = `io.open("foo.txt", "w+", closefd=False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Cannot use closefd=False with file name`

Comment: os.open requires a flag argument, so ... your code still errors. `>>> os.open("foo.txt")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: open() missing required argument 'flags' (pos 2)` ... you can fix it like this: `os.open("foo.txt", os.O_RDONLY)`

Comment: Sorry, but your post still does not answer the question: `Does “with io.open” close the file automatically?` because your code does not contain `with` (or `__enter__` / `__exit__`)